# Find a formula for $a_k$ for all $k\geq 1$ in a Taylor Series.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

Let $a_k$ be the coefficient of the $k$th-degree term of the Taylor series for the function $\log(x)$ about $x=2$. Find a formula for $a_k$ for all $k\geq 1$.

Comment: If you know that series expansion of $1/(u+2)$ about u=0, you shall know that of its antiderivative. Then let x=u+2.

Answer (score 1):

$$
a_{k}=\frac{f^{(k)}(2)}{k!}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^kk}
$$
Which was derived by looking for a pattern in $f^{(k)}(x)$ where $f(x)=\log x$ and dividing by $k!$ as Taylor's theorem requires.